# How can I change background Color of Stepper in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to the change the background color for stepper but this code change the background color for text too. I want to change only the stepper's background color. please guide me to solve this issue.

```
    HStack {

    Text("Count : ")
        .font(.body)
        .foregroundColor(Color(.blue))

    Spacer()

    Stepper(value: self.$MyViewModel.MyModel.minCounts, in: 5...60) {

     Text("\(String(format: "%.0f",MyViewModel.MyModel.minCounts)) Mins")
         .font(.body)
         .foregroundColor(Color("font"))

    }
    .background(Color("Color1"))
}
```

Comment: Can't you just add a `.background` to the `Text` element? It's annoying, in a way, that modifiers on a parent container affect children too, but according to the SwiftUI tutorial, it's expected that you do things like add modifiers to cancel animations on child elements.

Comment: thank you for the reply. but I don't want background for the `Text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give UIColor to Color;

```
Stepper(value: $age, in: 1...60)
        {
            Text("\(String(format: "%.0f",44.456)) Mins")
                .font(.body)
                .foregroundColor(Color("font"))
        }
        .background(Color(UIColor(named: "Color1")!))
```

You need to unwrap `UIColor(named: "Color1")` as it is an optional value. You can do it in different ways according to what you need. One solution might be like;

```
    let color1: UIColor = UIColor(named: "Color1") ?? .white
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
                Text("Count : ")
                    .font(.body)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.blue))
        Spacer()
        Stepper(value: $age, in: 1...60)
        {
            Text("\(String(format: "%.0f",44.456)) Mins")
                .font(.body)
                .foregroundColor(Color("font"))
        }
        .background(Color(color1))
        
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but I'm getting an error. please check my edited question

Comment: you need to unwrap color because  it is not certain that UIColor(named: "Color1") exists, it is optional.

Comment: thank you now the error is gone. but the stepper's original colour (gray) is lightly showing up. because I'm using light colour for the background. do you have any idea to fix that?

Comment: it looks like you can only give .backgroundColor and .foregroundColor. + and - buttons' background colors stay same.

Answer (score 1):

my two cents as I arrived here for deeper need: to completely customise Stepper.

I searched a bit, then I found a nice tip from https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/100-days-of-swiftui/custom-stepper-view/13742

and I rewrote a bit more usable.

code is below.

Just a couple of notes:

- be careful using double, adding 0.1 20 times does NOT give back 2.. as upper bound.. (better with Ints, eventually replace Double)
- we can also customize icons, but not for a stepper similar to Apple one.

Coding logic: use 2 buttons, if in range, go up/down, and binding will propagate to main view.

```
//  Created by ing.conti on 30/07/22.
//

import SwiftUI

typealias CallBack = ( ()->() )?

struct StepperColors{
    let leftBtnColor: Color
    let rightBtnColor: Color
    let backgroundColor: Color
}

struct ColoredStepper: View {
    
    internal init(
        value: Binding<Double>,
        range: ClosedRange<Double>, step: Double,
        onIncrement: CallBack, onDecrement: CallBack,
        stepperColors: StepperColors) {
            _value = value
            self.range = range
            self.step = step
            self.onIncrement = onIncrement
            self.onDecrement = onDecrement
            self.stepperColors = stepperColors
            
        } // init
    
    @Binding private var value: Double
    private let range: ClosedRange<Double>
    private let step: Double
    private let onIncrement: CallBack
    private let onDecrement: CallBack
    private let stepperColors: StepperColors
        
    
    private func checkValue(){
        if value < range.lowerBound {
            value = range.lowerBound
        } else if value > range.upperBound {
            value = range.upperBound
        }
    }
    

    var body: some View {
            HStack {
                
                Button {
                    decrement()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "minus")
                        .frame(width: 38, height: 35)
                }
                .foregroundColor(stepperColors.leftBtnColor)
                .background(stepperColors.backgroundColor)

                Spacer().frame(width: 2)
                
                Button {
                    increment()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .frame(width: 44, height: 35) // DONT ask WHY different from previous, apple bug.
                }
                .foregroundColor(stepperColors.rightBtnColor)
                .background(stepperColors.backgroundColor)
            }// HStack
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
            .onAppear(perform: checkValue)
                       
    }// View
    
    func decrement() {
        if value >= range.lowerBound + step {
            value -= step
            onDecrement?()
        }
    }
    
    func increment() {
        if value + step <= range.upperBound {
            value += step
            onIncrement?()
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value = 0.1
    
    private let stepperColors = StepperColors(leftBtnColor: .red, rightBtnColor: .green, backgroundColor: .white)
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            ColoredStepper( value: $value, range: 1.0...2.01, step: 0.1,
                           onIncrement: { print("Incremented") },
                            onDecrement: { print("Decremented")},
                            stepperColors: stepperColors )

            let text = "\(value.formatted())"
            Text(text)
            Spacer()

            }
        
    }
    
}
```